# When it is said "the DOM is ready" is the same as saying "the page is loaded"?

Tags: language-agnostic

when it is said "the DOM is ready" is the same as saying "the page is loaded" ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2):

No. The DOM is ready before the images (for example) have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post:

- [$(document).ready vs. $(window).load](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

**document ready**

> The document ready event executes
>   already when the HTML-Document is
>   loaded and the DOM is ready, **even if
>   all the graphics haven’t loaded yet**.
>   If you want to hook up your events for
>   certain elements before the window
>   loads, then $(document).ready is the
>   right place.

**window load**

> The window load event executes a bit
>   later when the complete page is **fully
>   loaded, including all frames, objects
>   and images**. Therefore functions which
>   concern images or other page contents
>   should be placed in the load event for
>   the window or the content tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "ready". The "DOM ready" event only means that the document structure has been fully created and is ready to be manipulated.

See the [JQuery's .ready() API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more informations.